# Unable to call Controller Method from view via javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-2

I am calling a controller method from java script the method works fine i can see the alter but while debugging the control never goes to the controller method .. here is the 
script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function confirmDelete(customerID) {


        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to Delete?')) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Home/Delete',
                data: { ID: customerID },
                success: function () {
                    alert('Added');
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            // Do nothing!
        }
    }
</script>
```

here is the "Home" controller method

```
public ActionResult Delete(String ID)
        {
            data.Delete(ID);
            return View("Home");
        }
```

**Update:**

and here is how i am calling this JS function

```
<a href="#"  onclick="confirmDelete(<%=clientsModel.UserID %>);" style=" cursor:pointer;"> <img alt="delete" src="../../Images/icons-png/delete-black.png" /> </a>
```

Comment: Check that whether you get value of customerID?

Comment: You're using a jQuery ajax call so you have to wrap your code with `document.ready`.

Comment: @sid : yes i have checked it in fireBug i am getting value of CustomerID

Comment: @Niklas : i am calling this method on a link click , check the updated question

Comment: url is wrong i think so

Comment: instead of  ``url: 'Home/Delete'`` try  ``url: '<%= Url.Action("Delete","Home")%>'``

Answer (score 0):

Here is Solution :
Add base URL Before your controller name

`$.post(baseUrl + '/' + controller + '/' + method, data, onSuccess).error(function (err) {
        if (onError) onError(err);
    });`

here baseUrl Will be like

'httpsORhttp://Domain/SiteName'

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
            $.ajax({
                    url: "URL",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    data: JSON.stringify("VARIABLE TO PASS"),
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert(response);
                    },

                    error: function (x, e) {
                        alert('Failed');
                        alert(x.responseText);
                        alert(x.status);
                    }
                });
```